# How to validate a currency formate with negative sign

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm doing an assertion to check the currency(US Dollar) the part of assertion include where I have to display in the report if the transaction is "Credit" or "Debit". However, I've done the code where I'm asserting that it's a valid currency but the issue is the currency value I'm getting through the application contains "-" sign, therefore, I have to print its a credit transaction.

> I'm thinking of following an approach where I can check if the currency
>   has "-" sign in front I'll print the results "credit transaction"

```
BigDecimal posted_trans = validator.validate(getDriver().findElement(by("label.transaction_amt")).getText(), Locale.US);
System.out.print("transaction amount = "+getDriver().findElement(by("label.transaction_amt")).getText());
                AssertUtil.assertFalse("Validate posted balance format", posted_trans==null);
```

> I'm getting print statement in this form console is
>
> transaction amount = -$12,345,67899

is there any approach I can take with currencyValidator function or I should take approach where I'll checking amount has "-" sign then print something ....??

Answer (score 0):

This Approach seems to work:

```
String transaction = "transaction amount = $12,345,67899";
    if(transaction.contains("-")) {
        System.out.println("credit");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Debit");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `BigDecimal`, you can check for negative number by using `signum` method.

```java
if (posted_trans.signum() < 0) {
    System.out.println("credit");
} else {
    System.out.println("Debit");
}
```

Another way is comparing with zero.

```java
if (posted_trans.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
    System.out.println("credit");
} else {
    System.out.println("Debit");
}
```